# Javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This may be completely stupid but given I type this into my browser console:

```
var arr = [];
arr.item = 'val';
console.log( arr );
arr;
```

What is the `arr;` syntax doing behind the scenes?  I'm assuming `console.log( arr );` is iterating all the properties of the `arr` object but what is `arr;` doing?  Also does `[]` tell me I'm dealing with an object of type array and `{}` tells me I'm dealing with an object of type object literal?  So `[ item: 'val' ]` is an object with a prototype of array and `{ item: 'val' }` is an object of prototype object literal?

Edit: Another way to ask this might be why are `console.log` and `arr;` different?

Comment: The item 'val` is an object, arrays can contain an object such as 'val'. Type 'foo' into the brackets and refresh, what does the console say now? It should contain a string 'foo' and object 'val'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the `arr;` syntax doing behind the scenes?

This is an *ExpressionStatement*. The JavaScript engine tries to evaluate the expression by reading the value of the variable, and then does nothing with it. If it occures inside a javascript function, it will do nothing (except when `arr` is not a variable, it will throw an error). If you just write `arr;` into the developer console, most browsers will echo the value of the last typed in expression, so you will see the value of `arr` as a result. The echoing mechanism is often implemented similar to `console.log`;

> I'm assuming `console.log( arr );` is iterating all the properties of the arr object

`console.log` prints a value to the developer console. If the value is a string, then the string gets printed. If the value is an object, then it is browser-dependent what happens. Most browsers, like Chrome will show an interactive representation of the object, like this:

[image]

Other browser might just call `toString` on the object, which in fact will iterate over the elements, and join them by commas.

> Also does `[]` tell me I'm dealing with an object of type array and `{}` tells me I'm dealing with an object of type object literal?

Yes and yes. `[1, 2, 3]` is an array literal, which will evaluate to a new instance of an array containing those values. `[]` is just an empty array. Arrays are instances of the type `Array`. `{a:1,b:2}` is an object literal, will evaluate to a new instance every time. `{}` is an empty object with no fields. Object literals evaluate to instances of the type `Object`.

> So `[ item: 'val' ]` is an object with a prototype of array and `{ item: 'val' }` is an object of prototype object literal?

No and yes. `[ item: 'val' ]` is invalid syntax. Array literals have elements separated by commas, they cannot have colons in them.

```
[ item: 'val' ]
VM154:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :(…)
```

The `:` *is* the unexpected token, the expression can't be evaluated because it has syntax errors.

On the other hand `{ item:'val' }` is a completely regular object literal with type `Object` and will have a single field named `item` with value `'val'`.

#### About object properties

In javascript, object do not have a fixed set of properties. Properties can be dynamically added and removed by writing them and by using the `delete` keyword. Every object has string (or Symbol) field names. An array can be seen as an object, optimized for integer keys. But still, keys are strings, so `a[0]` means the same as `a["0"]`.

```
var arr = [1, 2];
arr.item = 'val';    // assigns a new field to the object, called item
arr['item'] = 'val'; // does exactly the same as the previous
arr[1] = 3;          // sets the second item in arr to 3
arr['1'] = 3;        // does exactly the same as the previous
console.log(arr);
// prints [1, 2, item: "val"]
```

So arbitrary named fields can be assigned on an array, and when printed, Chrome does notice the object being an array, so uses array notation, but also prints the 'other' assigned values. It's important to mention that not every field gets printed, as `arr.length` is a fully featured property. It is the way guys at Google chose to print arrays. It is **not a valid JavaScript syntax**, it is just a (pretty good) visualisation of data inside an array.

#### About classes and prototypes

We say that `foo` is of class `Foo` if `foo` has the prototype `Foo.prototype`, in other words `foo.__proto__ === Foo.prototype`. Here `foo` is an object, `Foo` is a constructor function. As `Foo` itself is a function, `Foo.__proto__ === Function.prototype`.

If subtypes are involved, then we can say `bar` is an instance of `Foo`, if `bar` has `Foo.prototype` in it's prototype chain, i.e.: `bar.__proto__ === Foo.prototype || bar.__proto__.__proto__ === Foo.prototype || ...`. Explicitly accessing an object's `.__proto__` property is considered a bad practice and is strongly discouraged. Altering the `__proto__` value leads to serious performance drop, because it breaks the browser's optimisation strategies. So how to check if an object is of a type? You can use the `instanceof` operator.

Comment: I think the `[1, 2, 3, item: 'val']` syntax from `console.log` was helping confuse me as to what I was dealing with.  Since `typeof arr` returns `object` for both an array literal and an object literal there wasn't much help there either.  If `.__proto__` is not to be used and `.getPrototypeOf()` hasn't landed I guess you do introspection via `Array.isArray(arr);`?

Comment: @JSP Yes, for checking if a value is an array the best way is to call `Array.isArray(arr)`. For checking classes of arbitrary instances you have the `instanceof` operator. So `arr instanceof Array` might work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, started to type the comment and realized it was actually a full answer.
`console.log` yields an implementation dependent string representation of the argument. It does not iterate the properties of an object in most I've seen. String serializtions using the default `toString` method look like `[object Foo]` where 'Foo' is the internal class property of the object. You can see this for arrays by using `Object.prototype.toString.call([]);`.

The last line on the other hand, is just the value. How that gets represented as an evaluated expression in your browser console is implementation-dependent, but for all intents and purposes it does nothing and there is no reason you would want to write that.

Note that adding a property to an array with the `.` operator is almost *never* what you want: it does not add to the contents of the array but treats the array as an object. Iterating the indicies of the array will not yield that property, nor will its methods such as `.map` include it. Use `.push`. If you want string-keyed properties, use an object.

Comment: `console.log` only calls `toString` method on crappy browsers like IE8.

Comment: Still, "string representation of the argument" is not entirely correct. According to [the Firebug spec](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.log) (which has inspired most browser consoles), "if objects are logged, they will be written not as static text, but as interactive hyperlinks that can be clicked to inspect the object".

Comment: @Oriol its not in the standard, so I don't think I'm *too* far off saying 'implementation defined'.